# Captured image does not get saved on the device

Tags: android, image-capture

I am trying to save a camera captured image on the device. But it does not get saved.

//---manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I use the following code:

```
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

            try {
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "myimage.jpg");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                getImages();
```

Comment: Have you included the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

Comment: have you add permission in manifest?

Comment: yes i have added all permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See what i have done in my code for saving the captured image.

```
/*************************** Camera Intent Start ************************/

            // Define the file-name to save photo taken by Camera activity

            String fileName = "Camera_Example.jpg";

            // Create parameters for Intent with filename

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);

            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image capture by camera");

            // imageUri is the current activity attribute, define and save it for later usage

            imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            /**** EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI : style URI for the "primary" external storage volume. ****/


            // Standard Intent action that can be sent to have the camera
            // application capture an image and return it.

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

            /*************************** Camera Intent End ************************/


        }
```

onActivityResult method is here:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            /*********** Load Captured Image And Data Start ****************/

            String imageId = convertImageUriToFile(imageUri, CameraActivity);


            //  Create and excecute AsyncTask to load capture image

            new LoadImagesFromSDCard().execute("" + imageId);

            /*********** Load Captured Image And Data End ****************/


        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            Toast.makeText(this, " Picture was not taken ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, " Picture was not taken ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use your code and got an exception,   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=6550, uid=10103 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: you didn't added the permission in manifest file. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @User_1191 i added the onActivityResult method.

Comment: i added the permission

Comment: i added that in question. now am missing convertImageUriToFile()

Comment: i am testing the code on emulator,does it give problem?

Comment: No am using emulator only

Comment: i follow your given link it captures the image but not get saved

Comment: @User_1191 did you checked in FileManager --> DCIM --> Camera folder??

Comment: Done...i generate file name randomly.

Comment: i upvote it...but it will reflect later due to my reputation count.:)

Answer (score 0):

// don't use data.getData() as it return null in some device.

So use the cursor for getting captured Image.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
    Intent resultData) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);

    if (resultData != null) {

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index_data = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToLast();

            String imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
            Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath );
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage );

        }
```